# Report footer not showing in all pages of SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report which will show Company details. It contain one main report and a sub report. In main report, company name and company code are showing and in the sub report other company details like business type and financial details. In the main report footer i need to show the company name. For that i put the company name in a text box and that text box name is used in the expression like "ReportItems!CompanyName.Value".

Issue is that when I export the report to PDF, assume for a company it have two pages to show its details, the company name will show in the first page but not showing in the second page.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the Company Details **must** be in a subreport? I imagine you could avoid this problem by eliminating the subreport from your design.

Comment: There are some reasons to use sub reports. So not possible  to eliminate that.

Comment: Might not be the only reasons for you but in my experience subreports are either painful carryovers from Crystal Reports or a not-so-valuable mechanism for re-use.

Answer (score 0):

When a report with headers/footers is used as a subreport, only the body is rendered.  The header/footer for the parent report are used instead.

Check your parent report to make sure you've got the header/footer settings right.  The subreport header/footer settings do not matter.

Also, make sure your report properties are set appropriately for your main report.  The report body size + the report margins should equal the report page sizes.